# Boton cancelar de un Formulario Login C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

tengo un problema con este codigo del evento click del boton cancelar de un formulario login.

```
private void btnCancelar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show(@"Esta seguro que desea salir del sistema?", @"Atención",
                MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                Application.Exit();
            }
            else
            {
                txtUsuario.Focus();
            }
        }
```

Al pulsar el boton cancelar se abre un mensaje de advertencia de si estoy seguro o no de salir del sistema, al presionar "no" se estaria cerrando igual, agradeceria su ayuda.

Comment: pero, hiciste un trace del codigo, cuando es no, es no, y no deberia salir.

Comment: La logica del codigo es que si el boton presionado es "Yes" se cierra la aplicacion y caso contrario no seria que es no? osea hago foco en txt para que el usuario escriba su usuario.

Comment: si si. el codigo se ve perfecto, por eso no se que pasa. hay algo mas en tu codigo o algo en otro lado que pueda cerrar la app?

Comment: Coloca un breakpoint y revisa que es lo que pasa, porque a simple vista no veo errores. Confirma que estas entrando en el método.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si tu botón tiene la propiedad DialogResult = Cancel(Por ejemplo) el formulario lo interpreta como un 
si enviaras una respuesta DialogResult.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero para que funcione como quieres agrega esta linea de código:

```
private void btnCancelar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show(@"Esta seguro que desea salir del sistema?", @"Atención",
                MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                Application.Exit();
            }
            else
            {
                this.DialogResult = DialogResult.None;
                txtUsuario.Focus();
            }
        }
```

Un saludo

Comment: Muchas gracias!! ya se resolvio mi problema faltaba eso, al parecer a la opcion "no" no la esta tomando. Pero con eso se resolvio muchisimas gracias! Saludos.